# django - How to fix "the procedure entry point sqlite3_rtree_geometry_callback could not be located in the dynamic link library sqlite3.dll"

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I have problem with django project. I am facing error when i am trying to execute project in browser:

> "the procedure entry point sqlite3_rtree_geometry_callback could not
>   be located in the dynamic link library sqlite3.dll"

I have no idea where is the issue.